# How do I generate memoized recursive functions in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure, scope, closures, memoization

I'm trying to write a function that returns a memoized recursive function in Clojure, but I'm having trouble making the recursive function see its own memoized bindings. Is this because there is no var created? Also, why can't I use memoize on the local binding created with let?

This slightly unusual Fibonacci sequence maker that starts at a particular number is an example of what I wish I could do:

```
(defn make-fibo [y]
  (memoize (fn fib [x] (if (< x 2)
             y
             (+ (fib (- x 1))
                (fib (- x 2)))))))

(let [f (make-fibo 1)]
  (f 35)) ;; SLOW, not actually memoized
```

Using `with-local-vars` seems like the right approach, but it doesn't work for me either. I guess I can't close over vars?

```
(defn make-fibo [y]
  (with-local-vars [fib (fn [x] (if (< x 2)
                                  y
                                  (+ (@fib (- x 1))
                                     (@fib (- x 2)))))]
    (memoize fib)))

(let [f (make-fibo 1)]
  (f 35)) ;; Var null/null is unbound!?!
```

I could of course manually write a macro that creates a closed-over atom and manage the memoization myself, but I was hoping to do this without such hackery.

Comment: The solution given by @Phelix and @CarlosNunes is on the [ClojureDocs page for `memoize`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(defn make-fibo [y]
  (with-local-vars
      [fib (memoize
            (fn [x]
              (if (< x 2)
                y
                (+ (fib (- x 2)) (fib (dec x))))))]
    (.bindRoot fib @fib)
    @fib))
```

`with-local-vars` only provides thread-local bindings for the newly created Vars, which are popped once execution leaves the `with-local-vars` form; hence the need for `.bindRoot`.

Comment: Ding ding ding, thank you, we have a winner! But why did we have to jump into javaland to do the bindRoot? More importantly, doesn't this create a concurrency hazard if two threads do a .bindRoot at nearly the same time, before the vars are closed over when they exit the scope of this function? Is this still safe for concurrent creations of the generated Fibonacci functions? Or is the .bindRoot lexically scoped somehow? I'm still a little confused...

Comment: `.bindRoot` is `synchronized`, however this doesn't even matter here, since we call it on a local Var which is not accessible from any other thread at this point. As for the Javaish feel of a method call, I believe it is unavoidable here (`alter-var-root` won't work, since it requires *some* root binding to be already in place), but I don't see this as a problem. If anything, I wonder if I'd maybe prefer doing the same thing in some way not involving local Vars, but on the other hand, this does seem to be a particularly simple approach...

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. The bindRoot call creates a root binding of the var, however this binding is not shared with other threads because they have their own thread-local bindings of the var, and therefore the dynamic scoping of the vars doesn't bite us in the ass. Also, the bindRoot doesn't imply that the var will be visible from the toplevel.

Comment: The root binding *is* accessible from other threads through the machinery behind `memoize` -- the latter is, however, thread-safe. (But see [this blog post](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/03/memoize_done_right.html) by Meikel Brandmeyer for an in-depth analysis of memoization in Clojure and associated gotchas.) The Var is not, however, directly visible from anywhere except the body of the `with-local-vars` form (it's a Var *local* to that body) and so cannot be got at in any way after `make-fibo` returns except through calls to the returned function.

Comment: For future readers... I extracted this into a macro: https://gist.github.com/1136161

Answer (score 22):

There is an interesting way to do it that does rely neither on rebinding nor the behavior of `def`. The main trick is to go around the limitations of recursion by passing a function as an argument to itself:

```
(defn make-fibo [y]
  (let
    [fib
      (fn [mem-fib x]
         (let [fib (fn [a] (mem-fib mem-fib a))]
           (if (<= x 2)
             y
             (+ (fib (- x 1)) (fib (- x 2))))))
     mem-fib (memoize fib)]

     (partial mem-fib mem-fib)))
```

Then:

```
> ((make-fibo 1) 50)
12586269025
```

What happens here:

- The `fib` recursive function got a new argument `mem-fib`. This will be the memoized version of `fib` itself, once it gets defined.
- The `fib` body is wrapped in a `let` form that redefines calls to `fib` so that they pass the `mem-fib` down to next levels of recursion.
- `mem-fib` is defined as memoized `fib`
- ... and will be passed by `partial` as the first argument to itself to start the above mechanism.

This trick is similar to the one used by the Y combinator to calculate function's fix point in absence of a built-in recursion mechanism.

Given that `def` "sees" the symbol being defined, there is little practical reason to go this way, except maybe for creating anonymous in-place recursive memoized functions.

Answer (score 18):

```
(def fib (memoize (fn [x] (if (< x 2)
                              x
                              (+ (fib (- x 1))
                                 (fib (- x 2)))))))
(time (fib 35))
```

Comment: That is more typical style if you want the var bound in your namespace, but unfortunately you have incorrectly changed the function! What happened to the y parameter?!

Comment: `(fib 2000)` gives a StackOverflowError. The example above does not use recur, so stack overflows are inevitable, unless you "warm up" the memoization by calling the function for 1 to 2000. But how do you know that 2000 is big enough for an arbitrary use case? That's the rub!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
(def fibo
  (memoize (fn [n]
             (if (< n 2)
               n
               (+ (fibo (dec n))
                  (fibo (dec (dec n))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate the recursive memoized function pattern in a macro if you plan to use it several times.

```
(defmacro defmemo
  [name & fdecl]
  `(def ~name
     (memoize (fn ~fdecl))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cross between the [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) and Clojure's [`memoize`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5834):

```
(defn Y-mem [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (#(% %)
     (fn [x]
       (f #(if-let [e (find @mem %&)]
            (val e)
            (let [ret (apply (x x) %&)]
              (swap! mem assoc %& ret)
              ret))))))))
```

You can macrosugar this up:

```
(defmacro defrecfn [name args & body]
  `(def ~name
       (Y-mem (fn [foo#]
                 (fn ~args (let [~name foo#] ~@body))))))
```

Now for using it:

```
(defrecfn fib [n]
  (if (<= n 1)
      n
      (+' (fib (- n 1))
          (fib (- n 2)))))

user=> (time (fib 200))
"Elapsed time: 0.839868 msecs"
280571172992510140037611932413038677189525N
```

Or the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
(defrecfn edit-dist [s1 s2]
  (cond (empty? s1) (count s2)
        (empty? s2) (count s1)
        :else (min (inc (edit-dist s1 (butlast s2)))
                   (inc (edit-dist (butlast s1) s2))
                   ((if (= (last s1) (last s2)) identity inc)
                      (edit-dist (butlast s1) (butlast s2))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first version actually works, but you're not getting all the benefits of memoization because you're only running through the algorithm once.

Try this:

```
user>  (time (let [f (make-fibo 1)]
          (f 35)))
"Elapsed time: 1317.64842 msecs"
14930352

user>  (time (let [f (make-fibo 1)]
          [(f 35) (f 35)]))
"Elapsed time: 1345.585041 msecs"
[14930352 14930352]
```

Comment: It doesn't work recursively, though, and that far more important than just caching the single end value.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate memoized recursive functions in Clojure with a variant of the Y combinator. For instance, the code for `factorial` would be:

```
(def Ywrap
  (fn [wrapper-func f]
    ((fn [x]
       (x x))
     (fn [x]
       (f (wrapper-func (fn [y]
                      ((x x) y))))))))

 (defn memo-wrapper-generator [] 
   (let [hist (atom {})]
    (fn [f]
      (fn [y]
        (if (find @hist y)
          (@hist y)
         (let [res (f y)]
           (swap! hist assoc y res)
        res))))))

(def Ymemo 
  (fn [f]
   (Ywrap (memo-wrapper-generator) f)))

(def factorial-gen
  (fn [func]
    (fn [n]
      (println n)
     (if (zero? n)
      1
      (* n (func (dec n)))))))

(def factorial-memo (Ymemo factorial-gen))
```

This is explained in details in this article about [Y combinator real life application: recursive memoization in clojure](http://blog.klipse.tech/lambda/2016/08/10/y-combinator-app.html).