# Unexpectedly slow memoized function in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, memoization

While practicing Clojure, I was working on recursively counting walks that can only travel right or down on a graph (from Project Euler). It's a trivial problem, but I wanted to experiment with different ways of solving the problem.

```
(defn path-count [x y] (cond
                     (or (< y 0) (< x 0)) 0
                     (= y 0) 1
                     :else (+ (path-count x (- y 1))
                              (path-count (- x 1) y))))

(def path-count-memoized (memoize path-count))

(defn cartesian-range [min max]
(for [y (range min max)
      x (range min max)]
     [x y]))

(map 
  (fn [pair] 
    (path-count-memoized 
      (nth pair 0) 
      (nth pair 1))) 
  (cartesian-range 0 20))
```

Looking at it, it looks like it should perform asymptotically similarly to an iterative solution starting with (0,0) that uses a 20x20 array. However, it's extremely slow. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm thinking I'm misunderstanding how the memoization cache works [or hitting a size limit - that seems ridiculous though], or I'm misunderstanding the order in which map evaluates terms of a lazy sequence.

Comment: The misconception here is that `memoize` somehow "modifies" an existing function. It doesn't. It creates a new function, which is a memoized version of an existing function.

Comment: Basically - However, I was actually assuming something slightly different - that the function created by `memoize` replaced recursive invocations of the original function with recursive invocations of the memorized version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

path-count is not calling the path-count-memoize inside itself, so you're not actually getting much memoization. Setting that up is kind of tricky and there are a couple techniques to be found here:

[How do I generate memoized recursive functions in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906831/how-do-i-generate-memoized-recursive-functions-in-clojure)